# Find or prove that an equation mirrors inequality with another equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to make a computer search for the best set of items a,b,c,d run faster.  Calculating the best requires calculating $f(a,b,c,d)$ many times so I'm looking for $g(a,b,c,d)$ that could be easier for the computer to calculate.

More formally...

Given:

$f(a,b,c,d)=1-((1-a/100)*(1-b/100)(1-c/100)(1-d/100))$

$0<=a<=25$,
$0<=b<=25$,
$0<=c<=25$,
$0<=d<=25$

I'm looking for an equation $g(a,b,c,d)$ such that if

$f(a,b,c,d) < f(i,j,k,l)$

then

$g(a,b,c,d) < g(i,j,k,l)$

Preferably where $g(a,b,c,d)$ is composed addition operations between a,b,c,d.

Something like: $g(a,b,c,d)=log(a)+log(b)+log(c)+log(d)$, though I'm not sure how to prove if that would be a valid formula for $g(a,b,c,d)$

Comment: `Something like: g(a,b,c,d)=log(a)+log(b)+log(c)+log(d)` Replacing plain divisions and multiplications with calls to transcendental functions like $\,\log\,$ will not make anything `run faster`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using
\begin{align}
f(a,b,c,d)
&=
1 - \left(1 -\frac{a}{100}\right) \left(1 -\frac{b}{100}\right)
\left(1 -\frac{c}{100}\right) \left(1 -\frac{d}{100}\right) \\
&=
1 - 
\left(\frac{100}{100} - \frac{a}{100}\right) 
\left(\frac{100}{100} - \frac{b}{100}\right)
\left(\frac{100}{100} - \frac{c}{100}\right) 
\left(\frac{100}{100} - \frac{d}{100}\right) \\
&=
1 - 
\left(\frac{100-a}{100}\right) 
\left(\frac{100-b}{100}\right)
\left(\frac{100-c}{100}\right) 
\left(\frac{100-d}{100}\right) \\
&=
1 - \frac{(100-a)(100-b)(100-c)(100-d)}{100^4} \\
&=
\frac{100^4 - (100-a)(100-b)(100-c)(100-d)}{100^4}
\end{align}
will reduce the number of division operations from four to one.

**Update:**

The idea from your comment gives further improvement:
$$
f(a,b,c,d) < f(e,f,g,h) \iff \\
\frac{100^4 - (100-a)(100-b)(100-c)(100-d)}{100^4} < \\
\frac{100^4 - (100-e)(100-f)(100-g)(100-h)}{100^4}
$$
Multiplying both sides by $100^4$ gives the equivalent inequality
$$
100^4 - (100-a)(100-b)(100-c)(100-d) < \\
100^4 - (100-e)(100-f)(100-g)(100-h)
$$
Subtracting $100^4$ from both sides leaves
$$
-(100-a)(100-b)(100-c)(100-d) < -(100-e)(100-f)(100-g)(100-h)
$$
Multiplying both sides by $-1$ gives
$$
(100-a)(100-b)(100-c)(100-d) > (100-e)(100-f)(100-g)(100-h) \\
$$
where the order has flipped from $<$ to $>$.

So your $g$ would be
$$
g(a,b,c,d) = -(100-a)(100-b)(100-c)(100-d)
$$
or you use
$$
h(a,b,c,d) = (100-a)(100-b)(100-c)(100-d)
$$
with the flipped order:
$$
f(a,b,c,d) < f(e,f,g,h) \iff h(a,b,c,d) > h(e,f,g,h)\\
$$

Comment: And you can avoid that one division by multiplying by 1e-8 instead.

Comment: So:
$f(a,b,c,d)<f(e,f,g,h)  ==>$

$(1-a/100)(1-b/100)(1-c/100)(1-d/100) > (1-e/100)(1-f/100)(1-g/100)(1-h/100)$

Comment: OK, please check my updated and extended answer. I added more steps to make it easier to follow.